# I am trying to implement TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY in JDBC. But it dont show any exception when I try to move backward in resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to implement TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY in JDBC. But it dont show any exception when I try to move backward in resultset.
What I am doing wrong Here.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class ResultSet_Example {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver installed");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/j2ee?useSSL=false", "root","abhinav123");
        System.out.println("Connection established");
       // Statement d = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        //d.executeUpdate("create table info(id int,name varchar(20),sirname varchar(20))");
        DatabaseMetaData md = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
        if(md.supportsResultSetHoldability(ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT))
        System.out.println("This Database Hold Cursor over Commit");
        else if(md.supportsResultSetHoldability(ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT))
           System.out.println("This Database Hold CLOSE_CURSOR_AT_COMMIT"); 
        Statement d = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        String query = "select * from info";
        ResultSet rs = d.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }

    }

}
```

Following is The Output:

```
Connection established
This Database Hold Cursor over Commit
2
2
2
abhinav
abhinav
abhinav
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

**NOTE**
I am using Jdk 8

Comment: What database backend?

Comment: You are not "implement(ing) TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY in JDBC", because that implies that you are implementing a JDBC driver, which you are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html result sets are completely cached in memory by the Java driver.  You can disable this behavior by specifying

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                            java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

***AND***

```
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Without the fetch size setting it is implied (but not explicitly stated) that you'll get the caching behavior.

Setting the fetch size to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` forces the driver to retrieve each row from the database as it is requested by your Java code, instead of fetching the entire resultset (or a large batch of records) in one operation.  Turning off caching in this manner will *drastically* reduce the performance of your code (make it slower) for large result sets.  However, if you absolutely require that the result set be incapable of going backwards, this is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Can You elaborate how this worked.

Comment: See the update to my answer.  I am curious why you care that the result set not be rewindable.

Comment: I am doing a project that is why I require to do so.

Comment: You should ask yourself if the reduced performance is worth it. I.e. what is the consequence to your application if the result set is not functionally `FORWARD_ONLY`